# MongoDB insert with Node.js driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to find out why my ReST server won't insert more than one document to a collection.

The following works fine, but if I try to create a new, slightly different document, nothing happens.

```
Cruds.prototype.save = function(collectionName, obj, callback) {
    console.log('obj', obj);
    this.getCollection(collectionName, function(error, the_collection) {
        if( error ) callback(error)
        else {
            obj.created_at = new Date(); 
            the_collection.insert(obj, {safe: true}, function() {
                callback(null, obj);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Above, simply checks for the collection and inserts the document.  Works only once when I start the server and post to it.  Subsequent posts don't save.  Is the connection auto-closing?  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Your not checking the error status of the insert, which might inform you of something. Some logging might point you somewhere. The write concern `{ safe: true }` is deprecated BTW. Not really enough information here to tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  After logging, I realized that the ObjectId was not being uniquely generated on insert (which I didn't really expect) and thus creating unique key conflicts.  The solution is to pass the ObjectId along with the insert, like so:

```
Cruds.prototype.save = function(collectionName, obj, callback) {
    console.log('obj', obj);
    this.getCollection(collectionName, function(error, the_collection) {
        if( error ) callback(error)
        else {
            obj._id = ObjectID();
            obj.created_at = new Date();
            var document = merge(schema.user, obj);
            the_collection.insert(document, {safe: true}, function(err, result) { 
                callback(err, result);
            });
        }
    });
};
```